# Firebase login with LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using LinkedIn's SDK to create a token for a user. However when I try to pass this to Firebase it doesn't work. How do I make a Cloud Function for Firebase that I can call from my app that will generate the custom token for me?